# Converting A Value In A Dictionary to List

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I have a list of dictionaries. Here are some of the entries in the dictionary that I'm trying to search through.

```
[{
    'title': '"Adult" Pimiento Cheese ',
    'categories': [
        'Cheese',
        'Vegetable',
        'No-Cook',
        'Vegetarian',
        'Quick & Easy',
        'Cheddar',
        'Hot Pepper',
        'Winter',
        'Gourmet',
        'Alabama',
        ],
    'ingredients': [
        '2 or 3 large garlic cloves',
        'a 2-ounce jar diced pimientos',
        '3 cups coarsely grated sharp Cheddar (preferably English, Canadian, or Vermont; about 12 ounces)'
            ,
        '1/3 to 1/2 cup mayonnaise',
        'crackers',
        'toasted baguette slices',
        "crudit\u00e9s",
        ],
    'directions': ['Force garlic through a garlic press into a large bowl and stir in pimientos with liquid in jar. Add Cheddar and toss mixture to combine well. Stir in mayonnaise to taste and season with freshly ground black pepper. Cheese spread may be made 1 day ahead and chilled, covered. Bring spread to room temperature before serving.'
                   , 'Serve spread with accompaniments.'],
    'rating': 3.125,
    }, {
    'title': '"Blanketed" Eggplant ',
    'categories': [
        'Tomato',
        'Vegetable',
        'Appetizer',
        'Side',
        'Vegetarian',
        'Eggplant',
        'Pan-Fry',
        'Vegan',
        "Bon App\u00e9tit",
        ],
    'ingredients': [
        '8 small Japanese eggplants, peeled',
        '16 large fresh mint leaves',
        '4 large garlic cloves, 2 slivered, 2 flattened',
        '2 cups olive oil (for deep frying)',
        '2 pounds tomatoes',
        '7 tablespoons extra-virgin olive oil',
        '1 medium onion, chopped',
        '6 fresh basil leaves',
        '1 tablespoon dried oregano',
        '1 1/2 tablespoons drained capers',
        ],
    'directions': ['Place eggplants on double thickness of paper towels. Salt generously. Let stand 1 hour. Pat dry with paper towels. Cut 2 deep incisions in each eggplant. Using tip of knife, push 1 mint leaf and 1 garlic sliver into each incision.'
                   ,
                   "Pour 2 cups oil into heavy medium saucepan and heat to 375\u00b0F. Add eggplants in batches and fry until deep golden brown, turning occasionally, about 4 minutes. Transfer eggplants to paper towels and drain."
                   ,
                   'Blanch tomatoes in pot of boiling water for 20 seconds. Drain. Peel tomatoes. Cut tomatoes in half; squeeze out seeds. Chop tomatoes; set aside.'
                   ,
                   "Heat 4 tablespoons extra-virgin olive oil in large pot over high heat. Add 2 flattened garlic cloves; saut\u00e9 until light brown, about 3 minutes. Discard garlic. Add onion; saut\u00e9 until translucent, about 5 minutes. Add reduced to 3 cups, stirring occasionally, about 20 minutes."
                   ,
                   'Mix capers and 3 tablespoons extra-virgin olive oil into sauce. Season with salt and pepper. Reduce heat. Add eggplants. Simmer 5 minutes, spooning sauce over eggplants occasionally. Spoon sauce onto platter. Top with eggplants. Serve warm or at room temperature.'
                   ],
    'rating': 3.75,
    'calories': 1386.0,
    'protein': 9.0,
    'fat': 133.0,
    }]
```

I have the current code that is searching through the dictionary and creating a list of recipes that contain all the words in the query argument.

function to find the matching recipes and return them in a list of dictionaries. `tokenisation` is another function that basically removes all punctuation and digits from the query as well as make it lower case. It returns a list of each word found in the query.

For example, the query `"cheese!22banana"` would be turned to `[cheese, banana]`.

```
def matching(query):
        
    #split up the input string and have a list to put the recipes in
    token_list = tokenisation(query)
    matching_recipes = []
    
    #loop through whole file
    for recipe in recipes:
        
        recipe_tokens = []
        
        #check each key
        for key in recipe:
    
            #checking the keys for types
            if type(recipe[key]) != list:
                 continue
             
            #look at the values for each key
            for sentence in recipe[key]:
                #make a big list of tokens from the keys
                recipe_tokens.extend([t for t in tokenisation(sentence)])
    
        #checking if all the query tokens appear in the recipe, if so append them
        if all([tl in recipe_tokens for tl in token_list]):
            matching_recipes.append(recipe)
            
    return matching_recipes
```

The issue I am having is that the first key in the dictionary isn't a list, so as a result the function isn't checking if the words appear in the title and instead is just checking every other key and then adding each word to a list. I then check if every word in the query is present in the list of words in the recipes. The issue I am having is that because it's skipping the title as it's not in a list, if the word appears in the title, it won't return the recipe.

How would I add this title check into this code? I've tried turning it into a list as the title current has type string but then get a 'float' is not iterable error and have no clue how about tackling this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the error, simply replace the

```
if type(recipe[key]) != list:
```

to

```
if type(recipe[key]) == str:
```

Or better,

```
if isinstance(value, str):
```

You get the error from trying to use the `tokenisation` function on certain values, because there are values in the `dict`s that are indeed of type `float`, for example, the value of the `'rating'` key.

If the `tokenization` function returns a list of sentences, this should work:

```
def matching(query):
    token_list = tokenisation(query)
    matching_recipes = []
    
    for recipe in recipes:
        recipe_tokens = []
        
        for value in recipe.values():
            if isinstance(value, str):
                recipe_tokens.append(value)
                continue
            for sentence in value:
                recipe_tokens.extend(tokenisation(sentence))
                
        if all([tl in recipe_tokens for tl in token_list]):
            matching_recipes.append(recipe)

    return matching_recipes
```

If it returns a list of words:

```
def matching(query):
    token_list = tokenisation(query)
    matching_recipes = []
    
    for recipe in recipes:
        recipe_tokens = []
        
        for value in recipe.values():
            if isinstance(value, str):
                value = tokenisation(value)
            for sentence in value:
                recipe_tokens.extend(tokenisation(sentence))
                
        if all([tl in recipe_tokens for tl in token_list]):
            matching_recipes.append(recipe)

    return matching_recipes
```